# Decrypting GnuPG-encrypted files

Tags: encryption, gpg

I have some RNA-seq files need to be decrypted.

For example

```
1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz.gpg
```

Likely I have key for that in same folder

```
1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.gpgkey
```

I have also have a file name

```
1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.md5
```

Inside that I have

```
884f9fa72fb7f6adbba95dc677eb0ec9  1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz.gpg
```

> EDITED

```
    [fi1d18@cyan01 fereshteh]$ gpg --decrypt --passphrase-file=1672_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA.gpgkey --output - 1672_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA.tar.gz.gpg | tar -xvzf -
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
can't connect to `/home/fi1d18/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or directory
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
1672_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA/
1672_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA/mapped_sample/
1672_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam.bai
1672_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA/mapped_sample/HUMAN_1000Genomes_hs37d5_RNA_seq_WTSI-OESO_036_a_RNA.dupmarked.bam
gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[fi1d18@cyan01 fereshteh]$
```

Comment: If the file were encrypted with `--cipher-algo AES256` then it would have it's own "integrity protection" and gpg would know if the file were corrupted. Right now with only tar/gzip complaining, it's not obvious if the encrypted file was changed/damaged, or if it's just not a valid .tar.gz file. You could try decrypting it (without the `-d` option gpg should still know what to do, and with the `--use-embedded-filename` option might help) then examine the resulting file with tar, or even `file` to see what it "looks like". [Or if the md5 file is accurate, then it does appear corrupted]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is, according to the GnuPG output that you show, a file encrypted using the CAST5 algorithm.  This is a *symmetric* encryption algorithm, meaning that you should just be able to use the passphrase in that `.gpgkey` file with `gpg --decrypt` to decrypt it (without importing it into your keyring; it's not that kind of key).

To decrypt the file and pass the decrypted data directly to `tar` for unpacking, you could use

```
gpg --decrypt --passphrase-file=1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.gpgkey --output - 1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz.gpg |
tar -xvzf -
```

This would read the key from the provided file, decrypt the message using that key, and pass the data on to `tar`.

If the file `1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.gpgkey` does not decrypt the message, then you will have to get in touch with whoever provided you with the encrypted file and ask them for instructions about how to decrypt it.

The `.md5` file is used to ensure that the `.gpg` file contains the correct data.  You can use it to verify the data like this:

```
md5sum -c 1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.md5
```

If this does not give the output

```
1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz.gpg: OK
```

then the file is corrupt somehow, and you need a fresh copy of it from wherever you got it.  If it says `FAILED`, then `gpg` and `tar` will not be able to decrypt and unpack the data.

---

The error shown at the end of the updated question (now deleted) is `Cannot write: Disk quota exceeded`.  This means that the files extracted from the archive are too big to fit in the space allotted to your account.

To fix this, either delete or compress files no longer needed, until you have enough space to extract the archive, or talk with your system administrator(s) and have them allocate more disk space to your account.

Comment: Sorry for both of the solutions you mentioned a box appears saying enter passphrase

Comment: @FereshTeh What does `gpg --version` output?

Comment: @FereshTeh You should also just be able to copy the passphrase from the `gpgkey` file into the dialog box.

Comment: I don't know exactly what I should copy and paste in the box

Comment: Try using the 'openpgp' Option : ' gpg --openpgp -c .....'
  This will hopefully circumvent the use of a key Agent.

Comment: @FereshTeh Stop pasting private passphrases into random boxes on the internet

Comment: @FereshTeh If you are unable to decrypt the message, then contact the originator of the two files and ask them about how you are supposed to decrypt it.

Comment: Sorry I got error

Comment: tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[fi1d18@cyan01 fereshteh]$

Comment: @FereshTeh See the new things added in my answer about the `.md5` file.

Comment: Thank you [fi1d18@cyan01 fereshteh]$ md5sum -c 1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.md5

1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz.gpg: FAILED
md5sum: WARNING: 1 of 1 computed checksum did NOT match

Comment: @FereshTeh Yeah, that's what I though. You have a corrupted file. You will have to get a fresh copy of it.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried for new file I am seeing unzipped files in a folder but I am also seeing this error after finishing the task. could you please look at error in edited part of post because I got confused that I have unzipped files but also I have error

Comment: @FereshTeh `Cannot write: Disk quota exceeded` means that you have run out of disk space. Either remove (or compress) unneeded files, or ask you system administrator(s) to allocate more space for your account.

Comment: Thanks a lot for bearing with me and be this much helpful. I tried the third file returning a new error. Perhaps something is going wrong with this data :(

Comment: @FereshTeh Sorry, you are changing the text in the question constantly. It's difficult to write an answer that is consistent, because with each edit you invalidate the answer I've just written. I can't answer an ever-changing question.  I suggest that you check your files against the MD5 file that you also have. If that checks out ok, and if you have enough file space to store the extracted archive, it should work. You now have all the tools you need. Anything else will have to be a new question, or a matter for your system administrators.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, have a nice weekend ahead. Thank you for helping me more than I expect and sorry for being too much silly in questioning

Comment: @FereshTeh Take care, and have a good weekend.

Answer (score 2):

The file is not encrypted with a public key, for which you would need a private key to decrypt anyway. So importing the key does not help you.

It is encrypted with passphrase (gpg -c ..), and hopefully the passphrase is in the gpgkey-file.

Try:

```
hexdump -C 1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.gpgkey
```

You should see (only) printable characters in the Output. If so, use the key to decrypt:

```
gpg -d 1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz.gpg < 1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.gpgkey > 1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz
```

This should create the file '1672_WTSI-OESO_005_w3.tar.gz'.

Comment: Thank you, both of your solutions likely working but not finished yet. I have added those to my edited post